# How may I simplify the registration process

Tags: 8, rng

I Try to use [RNG](https://www.drupal.org/project/rng) to allow student user to registrer for company interviews (the events). I set up a View on my event to allow student to register for an interview.

It seems a bit complex because they had to click on a link (register) to a page where they have to click on a create button under a select Identity where there is only one mandatory "My account" radio ?

Is there a better way to do that with RNG, or maybe a more suitable module, I am indeed trying to create a n,n relationship between user and event.

I give a try to basicCart module, but I don't need the order part.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and Views.

Once you create a **node flag**, then all the user needs to do is click on the node flag to register to the event/interview.

If you need to know which users have registered for an event, in Views, simply add a relationship of flag (can't remember the exact relationship name, but I am sure you can figure it out, might be "users who flagged").

Answer (score 1):

[RNG Quick](https://drupal.org/project/rng_quick) may be a suitable solution. It adds a block which is visible on the event page, so you don't need to click the 'Register' tab.

Answer (score 0):

The Flag method does work but it bypasses the built-in RNG settings, Those being Limit the number of registrations, Limit the number of registrants and allow duplicate registrations.

Quick Registration Block also works, but some may say it still falls within the "complex" process area.